# Need To Encode Vertical Bar/Pipe In Blogger Title In URL When Using HTML Twitter Share Button On Post

Tags: twitter, encoding, share, blogger

I'm trying to encode vertical bars in Blogger titles in urls because when I push an html tweet button on a post, Twitter's pop-up window doesn't show anything to tweet. However, when I encode the vertical bar to %7C, everything works fine.

For example, MSNBC uses vertical bars to split up their titles on Youtube, and I automatically embed their videos on one of my blogs. See here:

> President Donald Trump's Friday Tweet: 'Iran Is Playing With Fire' |
>   Morning Joe | MSNBC

https://us-gov.blogspot.com/2017/02/president-donald-trumps-friday-tweet.html

But if anyone tries to tweet the post, they get a blank screen with the url https://twitter.com/share?url=https://us-gov.blogspot.com/2017/02/president-donald-trumps-friday-tweet.html&text=President%20Donald%20Trump%27s%20Friday%20Tweet:%20%27Iran%20Is%20Playing%20With%20Fire%27%20|%20Morning%20Joe%20|%20MSNBC

But if I encode the vertical bars to %7C, the Twitter window works fine.

https://twitter.com/share?url=https://us-gov.blogspot.com/2017/02/president-donald-trumps-friday-tweet.html&text=President%20Donald%20Trump%27s%20Friday%20Tweet:%20%27Iran%20Is%20Playing%20With%20Fire%27%20%7C%20Morning%20Joe%20%7C%20MSNBC

I'm just wondering if there's an easy way to prevent this from happening in my blog template's html code. Or if there's a simple script to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the current share URL which is of the form -

```
<a expr:href='&quot;https://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;text=&quot; + data:post.title' aria-label='' class='resp-sharing-button__link' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Twitter</a>
```

Use the native sharing URL generator provided by Blogger -

```
<a expr:href='&quot;https://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;&amp;postID=&quot; + data:post.id + &quot;&amp;target=twitter&quot;' aria-label='' class='resp-sharing-button__link' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>Twitter</a>
```

This will generate the URL of the form -

```
https://www.blogger.com/share-post.g?blogID=BLOGID&postID=POSTID&target=twitter
```

This will then automatically redirect to Twitter sharing window with the Title and URL of the post auto-filled. The title of the post will be escaped. This sharing URL generator can also be used for generating sharing URLs for other social networks as well (aka `facebook`,`pinterest`,`email`,`googleplus` by replacing the `target` parameter)

The downside of this being that you can't add users to follow or add hashtags like you would normally be able to do when building the Twitter sharing URL.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But is there a way to just share the post title and post url? It includes the blog title at the beginning of every tweet.

Comment: Hi @DVNET-Dvolatility, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @KunalChowdhury No I didn't. I'm just using Add2Any buttons for now.